# Information Theory and Basic Entropy

Tags: probability, statistics, entropy

> Say there is two fair (identical) coins. Let Heads worth  one
>   point and tails is worth two points. We flip the two coins at a single
>   instance .
>
> Lets consider the two experiments $X$ & $Y$ on the set $S=$ **{2, 3, 4}**.
>   Experiment $X$ the set $P_x(x)$ is the probability that the sums of
>   the points on the two coins is $x$.  Experiment $Y$  $P_y(y)$ is the
>   probability that the max number of points is $\frac{1}{2}y$   (if we
>   have a tie the max number is the common number).
>
> Determine, with proof wich one of the entropies $H(X)$ & $H(Y)$ is
>   greater.

So I'm having a bit trouble getting started on this problem, first off I don't understand when they say 
"probability that the max number of points is $\frac{1}{2}y$"

Now I am able to compute the entropy for the first part of the problem. I would appreciate if I could get some feedback if I did it correctly.
$H(X) = -(\frac{1}{3}log(\frac{1}{3})+\frac{1}{3}log(\frac{1}{3})+\frac{1}{3}log(\frac{1}{3}))$

Comment: the problem statement is so badly worded that is practically impossible to understand it. I suggest you carefully revise it if you want to have a chance in getting answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the outcomes of the coins be denoted by $A$ and $B$, where $A,B \in \{1,2\}$. Note that $X=A+B$. Therefore,
$$\Pr(X=2)=\Pr(A=1)\cdot\Pr(B=1)=1/4,$$
$$\Pr(X=3)=\Pr(A=1)\cdot\Pr(B=2) + \Pr(A=2)\cdot\Pr(B=1)=1/2,$$
and
$$\Pr(X=4)=\Pr(A=2)\cdot\Pr(B=2)=1/4.$$

For the experiment $Y$, we compute $P_Y(y)$ by noting that $Y = 2\max\{A,B\}$. Observe that $$\Pr(Y=2)=\Pr(A=1)\cdot\Pr(B=1)=1/4,$$ and $$\Pr(Y=4)=1-\Pr(Y=2)=3/4.$$
Therefore,
$$H(Y)=\frac{1}{4}\log(4)+\frac{3}{4}\log(4/3).$$
Now compare $H(Y)$ with $H(X)$ to determine which one is greater.

Comment: Ah, so $P_X(x)$ the probabilities are different? can you explain how that is? I assumed that they were equal since we had two fair coins

Comment: @Temirzhan Check the updated answer.

Comment: Okay, so it's little bit clearer now. I'm really hung up on the initial details as sad as that is. Are the probabilities for A=1, A=2, B=1, B=2 equal to 1/2?

Comment: @Temirzhan Yes, the coins are fair. So the probability of head (1) equals the probability of tail (2).

Comment: did you make a mistake when calculating $H(Y)$ shouldnt it be $$H(Y)=\frac{1}{4}\log(1/4)+\frac{3}{4}\log(3/4).$$

Comment: @Temirzhan I used $-\log(1/a)=\log(a)$.